# $q one function to handle both success and callback

Tags: angularjs, q

I have one function `processResponse` that has logic to handle both successful and failed response. Now I use it like this:

```
return $http.get(url).then(processResponse, processResponse).then(function (data) {});
```

Is there any way to use $q in a way so that I specify the function only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is [no](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q), although if you want to run common code regardless of the result of your promise you can use `finally`